# Batch file that reads variables from a text file

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I am trying to automate a loadstate job and in other to do so I need to be able to read from a text file that has a list of new computer names mapped to the old computer name. So Scanstate exports a user state profile to a network folder that uses the %Computername% variable to create a folder for each computer scanned. The idea is to have a text file that matches NewComputerA=OldComputerA, NewComputerB=OldComputerB so that loadstate picks the usmt.mig file automatically and we just have to create the mapping on a text file. Does this make sense? is it doable?

Maybe something like:

```
If %Computername% == "NewComputerA" set %MigComputer% == "OldComputerA"
cd %Systemdrive%\usmt
"%CD%\Loadstate.exe" \\Server\user_states\%MigComputer%\usmt.mig /c /i:miguser.xml /i:migapp.xml /i:Network.xml /v:13
```

Syntax may not be entyrely correct as I am learning on the go but you get the idea of what I am trying to do here ... Any advice or recommendations?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Computers.txt:

```
NewComputerA=OldComputerA
NewLaptopB=OldDesktopB
```

batch script:

```
set "NewName="
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('type Computers.txt ^| findstr /bi "%Computername%="') do set "OldName=%%a"
if not defined OldName echo No match. & goto :eof
"%Systemdrive%\usmt\Loadstate.exe" \\Server\user_states\%OldName%\usmt.mig /c /i:miguser.xml /i:migapp.xml /i:Network.xml /v:13
```

`Any advice or recommondations?` Bookmark [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/) and visit it often.